# The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }

Tags: gas, error

The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" } on BSC Testnet.

Basically am trying to use custom contract to call AddLiquidityETH method from pancakeswap contract.
By hardcoding all other values and send only number tokens to add to Liquidity.

But am stuck with above error after deploying, How to tackle this?

Comment: There's a bug in the contract code you should fix it before deploying.

Comment: AddLiquidityETH expects amountETH which is at below line ,shall i use await here?                  
        (amountToken, amountETH) = _addLiquidity(
            token,
            WETH,
            amountTokenDesired*10**9,
            amounts[1],
            amounttmin,
            amounts[1]
        );                                
     address pair = PancakeLibrary.pairfor(factory, token, WETH);        
        IWETH(WETH).deposit{value: amountETH}();

Comment: Without enough code to reproduce the error is hard to say anything or debug anything. You can use ganache's fork mode to test a contract against the main network without spending real ether.